# Careers Email Incorrectly States that I'm Missing Location, Employment History in profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I just received a Careers email reminder stating that I should complete my profile. It lists my status as "open, but not actively looking" even though I have set my status to "actively looking" a long time ago, and "actively looking" is the status that appears when I log in to see my Careers CV/profile page.

Further, the email suggests that I need to provide my location (I already provide it in my CV/profile) and that I need to add work experience and/or education (again, all work experience and education is already listed).

Now I am worried that the version of my profile that I see when editing and previewing is actually not the same as the version employers can see -- and perhaps to employers it looks like I am not actively looking and that I don't list my previous work history, location, or education -- even though I intended to.

Can I confirm whether the email was just sent to me in error, or if there really is some unusual bug with my profile?

Comment: I'm looking into this, something a bit fishy going on :/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here:

- We had a bug that meant your current location wasn't geo-coded correctly. If you wipe out your current location, save it and then edit it again it will correct itself.
- All of your experience entries are empty. We don't consider your CV complete enough to put it into the candidate index due to this. Complete at least one entry with 150 characters of descriptive text and you'll be eligible for the index (and stop getting the emails).

Alternately, if you don't want the email and don't want to do any of the above you can opt out of receiving emails from the **Reminders** category.

Comment: On the experience entries topic, this is related to a Developer Story issue I posted. For me, I definitely do not want to provide tech details about my job in a format like a careers profile that can be viewed by strangers or web-scraped. For the actual on-the-job details, I want to require people to inquire for my resume. I'd really like to disable those reminders, because for me I definitely do not want to elaborate on this stuff on any career profile page. The same is true for education entries as well. I'm happy to share details about my graduate work only whenever people reach out to me.